# WordPress database connection to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, credentials

I want to know which tables in database where WordPress store credentials To connect to `MySQL`. Because I've changed the credential in my `WP_config` File and I have to do it even in my `WordPress` database table, but I don't know which table.

Comment: wordpress stores mysql connection credentials only in config file only

Answer (score 0):

The database access credentials (user, password, database) for Wordpress are *only* stored in the wp-config.php file. You only have to change them there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Guys for your help i resolved by deleting database user and creat new one and i changed the credentials and i worked